# How to use the pretrained MaltParser parsing models for english

Tags: java, nlp, text-parsing

I am trying to use the pretrained parsing model for English of the MaltParser by following the steps in the following page, but repeatedly getting a null pointer exception.
http://maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html

I am trying this on a MaltParser version 1.4 and Java version 6 on a Windows machine. I think the model was trained on a Linux machine as some directory info in the model suggests so. I am not sure if that is causing a issue. I searched the net for help but did not find anything specific to this.

Kindly help me to solve this issue. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use version 1.4.1.

From the version 1.4.1 release note:

> Fixed a problem introduced in 1.4 with
>   path separator in Microsoft Windows
>   environment

Answer (score 1):

maltparser ships with a few examples, e.g., maltparser-1.7.2\examples\apiexamples\srcex\org\maltparser\examples, that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me solve a big problem. I intended to parse many sentences (1.3 million sentences) using a certain langModel.mco but it was taking forever leading the .mco model file for each sentence. Now I can write a java program which loads the .mco file once and calls model.parseTokens() on each sentence.